# Device Size specific tab bar item in xcode 6 storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode6

In xcode 5, when creating a universal app, using storyboards I could create a separate storyboard for iPhone and iPad. This allowed me to add an extra tab into my iPad app tab bar controller if I had content specifically suited to the larger screen and I didn't want to present this content on the iPhone

In the xcode 6 world, I know we can use individual storyboards, but if I created a universal app using a single resizable storyboard and I had a tab that I only wanted to display on an iPhone 6+ and iPads how would I go about this? Or would I still have to split my storyboards in this instances and not have the extra content on the iPhone 6+? I appreciate that Apple are moving towards these flexibile widths, but there still might be instances where I only want specific pages available on devices above a particular size.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable at runtime. Call `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier],` access the list of other tabs using viewControllers property, and simply add the new controller where you want it. Alternatively, you could do it the other way and start with all view controllers and then remove the ones you don't want.